# ¿Como subir a shinyapps.io una aplicación R-Shiny que utiliza el paquete R LidR?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

El problema es que `rsconnect::appDependencies()` detecta el paquete R lidR cómo perteneciente a Bioconductor cuando en realidad pertenece a CRAN.

Package:lidR ,Version: 3.0.2 ,  Source: Bioconductor

El error es el siguiente:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 765333282 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unable to determine package source for Bioconductor package lidR: Repository must be specified
```

Ya no sé que más probar. La solución que suelen dar como válida no funciona:

```
options(repos = BiocManager::repositories())
```

Mi repositorio contiene lo siguiente:

```
getOptions ("repos")
```

BioCsoft:                                              "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.11/bioc",
BioCann: "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.11/data/annotation",
BioCexp: "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.11/data/experiment",                                            BioCworkflows: "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.11/workflows",
CRAN: "https://cran.rstudio.com/"

Gracias.

Comment: En el archivo server estas cargando los paquetes?

Comment: Si. Con library("lidR") ... library ("nombre_paquete") cargo cada paquete.

Comment: Hola estuve investigando un poco y parece que es debido a una dependencia que tiene el paquete de Bioconductor en este link es donde discuten del tema lo que mencionan como solución es utilizar la versión directamente de github https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/2716

Comment: Gracias Rubén. El problema es que el paquete descargado de GitHub no funciona :(